# How to delete a String element from String Set in DynamoDB using Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My table

[image]

I am trying to delete one string element "Nike" from existing StringSet in Dynamodb table name stacks. I executed:

```
var params={
TableName:"stacks",
Key:{
    Overflow:1
},
UpdateExpression:" DELETE LikeByUser :b ",
ExpressionAttributeValues:{
 ":b":dynamodb.createSet("Nike")
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
}
dynamodb.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
        
    

} else {
        console.log("Updated Successfully ");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

But got Error

> ValidationException: An operand in the update expression has an incorrect data type.

I tried REMOVE in place of DELETE but no show even then.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Something went wrong with your `LikeByUser`, it is not a set, it is look like a list of map object. it should be like `["Harsh", "Nike"]`.  and the first argument of `createSet` should be an array.